# Python - Library to Import Libraries

Tags: python, module

I am developing a project which has about a dozen different files.  At the top of each file I have almost the identical lines which import the same libraries and initializes a connection to my DB:

```
import re
import urllib2
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.sql import *
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import *
from table_def import Team, Player, Box_Score, Game, Name_Mapper
from datetime import timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import numpy as  np
import argparse

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///ncaaf.db', echo=False)
md = MetaData(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = Session()
teams_table = Table("teams", md, autoload=True)
games_table = Table("games", md, autoload=True)
box_scores_table = Table("box_scores", md, autoload=True)
players_table = Table("players", md, autoload=True)
names_table = Table("names", md, autoload=True)
```

Can I make a module to import all these modules and to initialize this DB connection? Is that standard? Or dumb for some reason I am not realizing?

Comment: You need _all_ those in dozen's of other files? If so, that's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: well not exactly, but i just copy and paste them all from file to file, rather then delete one line for a file here, add one line to a file there, etc.

Comment: Importing just what you need is better than importing a bunch of things 'just in case` they're needed, it's also more explicit which is considered a good thing. Also note that importing something that's already been imported in the same or another file is fairly cheap processing-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import something into your module, it becomes available as if it was declared in your  module itself. So, you can do what you want like this:

In `common_imports.py`:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import numpy as  np
import argparse
...
```

In `main_module.py`:

```
from common_import import *

a = np.array([])  # works fine
```

However this is not recommended since [**Explicit is better than implicit**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). E.g. if you do this, someone else (or even you from the future) won't understand where all these imported modules come from. Instead, try to either organize your imports better, or decompose your module into several ones. For example, in your import list I see argparse, SQL stuff and numpy, and I can't imaging single module that may need all these unrelated libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a package, you can import them in the `__init__.py` file, although I would suggest leaving them where they are to increase code-readability.